# How to get array of string from List<Tuple<int, int, string>>?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5

I was wondering is there an elegant way of geting `string[]` from `List<Tuple<int, int, string>>`?

I'm thinking of .NET way (preferable extension methods and lambda expressions :P)

P.S. Code is from .NET 3.5 project, so Tuple is my own implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var strings = list.Select(item => item.Item3).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string[] s = tuples.Select((t) => t.Value3).ToArray();
```

(assuming "Value3" is the third value of the tuple)