# Is there a way to change tuple values inside of a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, int, tuples

The array I'm using is `int[,,]` and I want to make the first value of each (what I assume to be) tuple in one method and then I want to modify the second two values several times. (in another method)

For example:

```
int[,,] MyArrayGet()
{    
    int [,,] myArray;
    int [,,] myArray = new int[9,9,9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = [SomeInt,0,0];
    }
    return myArray;
}
int[,,] MyArrayModify(int[,,] myArray)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (somthing is true) 
        {
            myArray[i] = [dont change this value,n+1,dont change this value]
        }
        if (somthingelse is true)
        {
            my  Array[i] = [dont change this value,dont change this value,n+1]
    }
}
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

I have checked this question [How to get array of string from List<Tuple<int, int, string>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070041/how-to-get-array-of-string-from-listtupleint-int-string) however either I do not feel it answers my question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131400/why-tuples-items-are-readonly

Comment: being a beginner, i do not understand the answers to the question you suggested, my apologize. @Tarik

Comment: I pointed you to an answer explaining that you cannot modify a tuple. I then provided an answer below that should do the job. Please, feel free to ask further for explanations. Please, post some code on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What you are creating is not a tuple. It is a 3-dimensional array,
consisting of 9*9*9 = 729 integer values. Are you expecting to have 9 tuples of 3 ints each? Then answer from @tommy is what you are looking for. Or create new int[9,3] - 9 rows, 3 columns each. BTW your for loop is out of bounds. Should be i < 9

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Tuple by design is immutable. Just create new one when modifying.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> Get()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(i, 0, 0);
    }
}

IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> Modify(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> tuples)
{
    foreach (var tuple in tuples)
    {
        if (tuple.Item1 < 5)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2 + 1, tuple.Item3);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3 + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Your code looks like javascript more than C#. `int[,,]` is 3D array not array of 3 items.

`Tuple<int, int, int>[]` is an array of `Tuple` of 3 items. If you are not a beginner and use LINQ, `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>>` is a better version.

Answer (score 6):

You have to replace the tuple you want to modify by a new tuple containing the updated value.
Alternatively, you can create a class with the fields that you need and public properties. That will only take seconds and probably make your code more readable.

Comment: Agreed, once you are starting to want to modify values, just create a class instead of creating more code to solve a simple issue.